# USB Keyboard changed keymap automatically

Tags: keyboard

My USB External keyboard layout changed to this format.

And I am unable to reset it back to normal one (US input). Any suggestions on how to reset  it back?

- Rebooted the system. No effect.
- Reset PRAM. No effect.
- I don't have an additional keyboard to try. But I can try it in a while.

[image: Keyboard Layout Changed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you're holding it down, or your Option key is stuck ;-)

Regular...

[image]

With Opt held - note the greyed key, marked in red

[image]

Also note this is a UK keyboard, but the main layout is the same UK/US